# How to properly localize large text?

Tags: reactjs, localization, jsx

I write an interactive article and want to translate it to several languages. The text is long (around 13 pages) and has a lot of html tags and some interactive elements inside.

I have seen a few localization libraries, but, as I understand, they are better in use for small amounts of text. What would be the proper way to keep its translations? Thank you in advance for the advices.

Comment: In my opinion it all depends on your tech stack and what you're trying to achieve. If your goal is to build something like a blog, you may try to look into JAMstack where you can store the text in different markdown files. An example of this would be https://github.com/gaearon/overreacted.io 
(`src/pages/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/`).

Comment: There's no generic answer to this, particularly since there's (apparently) embedded HTML and interactivity. A lot would depend on the nature of that interactivity, but it might be as simple as using tokens for all the I18N text and replacing them w/ the appropriate translation during render. Really hard to say w/o any info, though.